# Why is this max-height for image working in every browser except Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, layout

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2fhbjszn/4/

It works fine in chrome and safari, only firefox is calculating the height wrong causing slides to not fit container.

I am trying to create a set of floated left slides inside an absolute positioned container, however it looks like firefox stretches slide's height outside of the container height like if there was no max-height: 100% directive given.

This is my html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="absolute-container">
        <div class="slides">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/WLUHO9A_xik/download"/>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="https://unsplash.com/photos/pYxh7-ITaq8/download"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 900px; 
    height: 250px; 
    background-color:#aaa; 
    position:relative;    

    .absolute-container {
        position: absolute; 
        top: 30px; 
        bottom: 30px; 
        background-color: #DBD9C7; 
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
.slides {
    height: 100%;
    &:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
}

.slide {
    float:left; 
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: 5px;
    img {
        max-height: 100%; 
        max-width: 100%; 
        width: auto; 
        display:block;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2fhbjszn/3/ -- because the width of the two elements is greater than 100%?

Comment: But the height of images goes beyond the container, container should have "bottom: 30px;" but instead it goes outside of the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug in Firefox trying to calculate `<div class="slide">` width, as currently it  is computed as width of original picture before rescaling. Said that, fast workaround would be to set `max-height:` on image in pixels rather than relatively.

Comment: I have tried that but it looks like Firefox is calculating "slide" width even before my Javascript kicks in. My JS calculates image height in pixels depending on browser window size.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not completely following your use case. So this SCSS above is not compiled in advance and linked in headers, but applied from JavaScript?

Comment: No no, the jsfiddle is just a small example for illustration purposes only of what I have on my website. On my website I have tried all sort of JS and CSS workarounds and nothing seems to solve the issue.

Comment: That's why I wrote, I'm not seeing the whole picture. Setting max-height in pixels solves the issue in the form shown in the question (not that I like this solution). I've also tried some other tricks to force FF to recalculate div in additional pass, but so far nothing worked. I know that it's not in the spirit of SO, but maybe its time to give a link to your site, so I'll be able to see other interactions and understand why fixing dimensions to constant value is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I've had issues with display:table and min/max heights.  Try setting it to display:block and see if that sorts it. Then fix the other issues caused by that change!